# Remove sash when pivot shoe has no opening

Tags: window-frame

I'm having trouble removing a window sash. I unclipped the sash and pivoted it away from the wall, but I don't know how to remove it from there. I'm used to there being an opening in the  shoe that the pin can escape from. What am I supposed to do from here?

[image]

Comment: what is the screw for

Comment: I tried loosening it. It doesn't seem to be connected directly to the pin.

Comment: so what is it for ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you know?

Comment: take it out and the pin will become loose

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, once you've rotated the window into the room like this, you then holding it with one hand on each side of the sash, raise one hand and lower the other until it tips out of the slide frames. i.e. you twist it out almost as if you were unscrewing it.